# Rename Github repo from command line

Tags: git, github, repository, github-cli

I googled and also searched on stackoverflow for the below question, however was unable to find any satisfactory answer.

So say, I have a remote repository: `https://github.com/<username>/foo` and I
wish to rename it to `https://github.com/<username>/bar` at the remote site as well as in local config entries from command line, and right now I have the repo cloned locally at '~/my_github_repos/foo'.

So basically, I want all the things for this repo to be converted from `foo` to `bar` ( urls / configurations / local folder )

For that, I renamed the folder `~/my_github_repos/foo/` to `~/my_github_repos/bar/` and tried doing,

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<username>/bar.git
```

But that just did it locally and not remotely. So when I made some changes in the files inside the now renamed folder, `bar` and did a `git push origin master`, It gave me error:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/<username>/bar.git/' not found
```

*So, what all things do I need to do so that I make the changes locally and get it reflected remotely, for the renaming of repo ?*

I know Github.com provides a very nice UI for renaming the repos, however I just want to know if there is a way to do so in few steps from command line. If not, I agree that it's simple to just rename it from github.com website.

The reason for this question is that, I like to do things mostly from commandline rather than go here and there for doing tasks as simple as renaming a repo.

P.S. I searched stackoverflow and found this: [Rename Github Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312761/rename-github-repository), which may seem similar to this question, but it's different.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-repository-settings/renaming-a-repository

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-api%5D+rename+repository

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The local repository and the remote repository are separate in this regard. There is no Git-command that will allow you to change the path/name of a remote repository.

You mention in your question that you already changed the name of the local directory and updated the repository URL with `git remote set-url`. Because you cannot *rename* the remote repository with Git, you need to do this in a way that is supported by the type/software/platform of the actual remote repository you have.

This is tagged with *GitHub* so your question boils down to: *Is there a way to change the name of a GitHub repository without using the web-interface?* **Yes, this is possible with the GitHub API by sending a `PATCH` request to `/repos/{owner}/{repo}` and specifying a different `name` parameter** ([docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#update-a-repository)).

I suggest to use the [`api`-command](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) of GitHub CLI which allows to make authenticated request to the GitHub API in a secure way:

```sh
gh api -X PATCH --raw-field name=new-name repos/account-name/current-name
```

<sup>*There is a [feature request](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/1399) for GitHub CLI to allow renaming of a repository with a dedicated command rather than using the `api`-command.*</sup>

Another option is to use `curl` directly. However, passing credentials in the command line has security implications and I don't recommend doing this. For the sake of the example, here is how the request would look like:

```sh
curl -X PATCH \
  -d '{"name": "new-repo-name"}' \
  -H "Authorization: token ghp_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  "https://api.github.com/repos/account-name/current-repo-name"
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: The gh cli now supports rename directly without using the api commands.


`gh version 2.41.0 (2024-01-08)`<br/>
`gh repo rename bar`

https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_rename

Answer (score 2):

> I like to do things mostly from commandline rather than go here and there for doing tasks as simple as renaming a repo.

No need to use the API command anymore, with the [new gh 2.3.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.3.0).
It does rename the remote repository, with the same API call.
But: it does *also* rename the remote "`origin`" URL to match the new renamed repository URL.

See [PR 4450](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/4450) and [commit 67d1a90](https://github.com/cli/cli/commit/67d1a9012c6ec81eaef68bea74c9a9a95ee38cec), with [`pkg/cmd/repo/rename/rename.go#updateRemote() git.UpdateRemoteURL()`](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/67d1a9012c6ec81eaef68bea74c9a9a95ee38cec/pkg/cmd/repo/rename/rename.go#L141-L163)

But you can go even further with [gh extension](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/4802), as [illustrated here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzK3ZuiEjcA) by [Nate Smith](https://github.com/vilmibm).

---

[`gh` 2.6.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.6.0) (March 2022) add interactive repository edit functionality by [@g14a](https://github.com/g14a), which include repository renaming.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17702388/123090721-1b8da900-d446-11eb-939b-6ef8a21edb10.png]